# Enlarging a contour plot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I just started using *Mathematica*, and when I entered the following:

```
Manipulate[
  ContourPlot[x^4 + y^4 + 2*x^2*y^2 - x^2 + y^2 == n, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5,5}], 
  {n, -.2, 3}]
```

I got the Plot that I wanted, but it's incredibly small. Is there a way to make it larger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It  depends on what you mean by size. `PlotRange` will "zoom", `ImageSize` produces larger graphic.

For illustration:

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  x^4 + y^4 + 2*x^2*y^2 - x^2 + y^2 == n, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, 
  ImageSize -> imagesize], {n, -.2, 3}, {r, Range[2, 5]}, {imagesize, 
  Range[200, 500, 100]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

PlotRange is the answer:

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  x^4 + y^4 + 2*x^2*y^2 - x^2 + y^2 == n, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}
  ], {n, -.2, 3}]
```

Try also

```
PlotRange -> All
```

and

```
PlotRange -> Automatic
```

EDIT:
You can also do kind of a zoom with Manipulate[]

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  x^4 + y^4 + 2*x^2*y^2 - x^2 + y^2 == n, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
  PlotRange -> {{-xRange, xRange}, {-xRange, xRange}}]
 , {n, -.2, 3}, {xRange, .5, 5}]
```

[image]